# Is it possible to install pymedia on recent Ubuntu builds?

Tags: python, ubuntu, psychopy

I have all the dependencies for pymedia, but they are all "not found" by the installation script. I see that pymedia is no longer in active development, but just want to see if anyone has been able to install it on Ubuntu 14.04, on a 64-bit machine. I require it for a function in pyschopy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that pymedia hasn't been touched for 9 years I think you'll be struggling to build it. Is the aim to build a movie from some frames? I'd suggest outputting them from PsychoPy as png images and then combining them with ffmpeg. 
I intend in the future to add support back in to output movie files directly using pymovie to combine the frames (which uses ffmpeg in the background), but this isn't on the top of the priorities list! ;-)

Comment: That was the intention, and outputting/combining frames was something I was considering since I couldn't get it to build. Good to know my thinking was on the right track. Thank you for your reply!